# Getting error in react.js , TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am a beginner React.js learner. I dont know where did I made mistake and this is my first quesiton ever. This is my component List.js which I Sent props from another component calls Contact.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './List.css';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

 
class List extends Component {
    static propTypes={
        contacts:PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ListArea"> 
                <input name="filter" id="filter" placeholder={"Filter by name or phone"} /> 
                <ul className={"List"} >
                   {
                       this.props.contacts.map(contact =>   
                                           
                        <li>
                        <span className={"name"}>{contact.name}</span>
                        <span className={"phone"}>{contact.phone}</span>
                        <span className={"clearfix"}></span>
                        </li>
                        
                        
                    }
                   
                    
                </ul>
            
            
            
            
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default List;


import React, { Component } from 'react'
import List from "./List";
import "./List.css"
import Form from './Form';

class Contacts extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <List Contacts={this.props.Contacts}/>
                <Form/>


            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Contacts;
```

I am so inexperienced here sorry for my mistake

Comment: Please, add the code where List  is used

Comment: you are passing the property `this.props.Contacts` uppercase and reading it lower case `this.props.contacts`

Comment: The problem is not in the code that you have provided. It is in the code where you are using the List and passing `<List Contacts={this.props.Contacts} />`

Comment: @Rostyslav where did you see that code?

Comment: @Apostolos there was a comment by Elif few seconds ago. And it was deleted...

Comment: a ok sorry didnt catch that :)

Comment: this was the code sorry I couldnt add it to the code place

Comment: Ok, so as @Rostyslav said, you are passing wrong property `Contacts` vs `contacts`. change it to lowercase, use the check for `undefined` too and you will be OK.

Comment: and thanks you too @Rostyslav

Comment: Lets just stop guessing... Please, @Elif can you edit the question and provide the code where List is used instead of the code you have provided?

Comment: @Elif If the anwer fixes your problem, please accept it in order for this post to be considered "closed". Thank you :)

Comment: the lowering the C fixed. How I am gonna close this post I dont know :(( @Rostyslav

Comment: @Elif  I dont quite remember how this is displayed when you are the one that asks for help but i think at the left of each answer it has an option for that? sth like that

Comment: @Apostolos okayy I see I see

Comment: most probably :)

Comment: great. done. thnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contacts` may be undefined at first load.

Check if it exists and then use `map`

```
this.props.contacts && this.props.contacts.map(contact =>
```

OK, so after the updated comment, you are passing wrong property to `List` component. This, along with `undefined` check, should fix the problem

```
<div> <List contacts={this.props.Contacts}/> <Form/> </div>
```